# How can I share a custom function in RDLC file?

Tags: rdlc

I have rptShowTickets.rdlc and has a my own function named as "GenerateTimeString() in code section.

Now I want to create a new rptShowMonthlyTickets.rdlc and want to use same function used in "rptShowTickets.rdlc" custom function GenerateTimeString()

I know the one copy and paste the function in new .rdlc file.But I don't to put same code (function) because I want to reuse the function by sharing or other way in which rdlc allow.

I want to used in my mvc application folder not on report server.

I mean to asked May I share a function or put at common location,so it would be available for every .rdlc file?

Please do the need full.

Answer (score 0):

"Custom assemblies can be used to retrieve specialized functions that you plan to use in your reports" (from MSDN).

In your "Report Properties" dialog there is "Reference" tab. Use it to add your Custom Assemblies.

For more info see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153561%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).